# Drop down selection to match one item in array VueJS, JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get an exact match for my drop-down selections. So in this example, if I select 'apple' it runs the query okay but it also returns results for 'pineapple'too. How do I get an exact match only?

I have another function in my app that returns the uniqfruit data.

**The drop-down**

```
<select id="fruitselect"
                v-model="fruit"
                class="form-control"
                @change="fruitonChange($event)"
                :disabled="selectDisabledfruit"
              >
                <option disabled value="">Select fruit</option>
                <option v-for="fruit in uniqfruit" :key="fruit" :value="fruit">
                  {{ fruit }}
                </option>
              </select>
```

**The VueJS function**

```
fruitonChange: function (e) {
      var id = e.target.value;
      var fruit = e.target.options[e.target.options.selectedIndex].text;

      if (id === uniqfruit) {
        this.runquery();
      } else {
        e = "!showall";
      }
      console.log("id ", id);

      console.log("fruit ", this.fruit);
      console.log("uniqfruit ", this.uniquefruit);
    },
```

**Console results**

```
id  apple
fruit  apple
uniqfruit  Proxy {0: 'apple', 1: 'banana', 2: 'pineapple', 3: 'kiwi'}
```

Comment: I think the issue is with the function that finds the fruit. Can you add that?

Comment: The data is pulled in using an Axios request. Im not sure it can be that as it works okay elsewhere. I amended the code above as I had made a mistake at the if (id === this.uniquefac)  part